Обязательно ли второе тире после "прочее"?
Рады сообщить, что непродовольственные товары – одежду, обувь, косметику и прочее теперь можно приобрести и через маркетплейсы.

Правильно:
Рады сообщить, что непродовольственные товары – одежду, обувь, косметику и прочее – теперь можно приобрести и через маркетплейсы.
Пояснение

Это обособление однородного ряда в теме "Обобщающие слова":
5. Если однородные члены предложения носят 
характер приложения или уточнения, то после 
обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может 
ставиться тире: Алый свет нежно заливал 
окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши 
машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы (Кат.); 

8. Если однородные члены предложения, стоящие 
после обобщающего слова, не заканчивают собой 
предложения, то перед ними ставится двоеточие, а 
после — тире: Разве все эти вещи: карандаш в 
оправе, записная книжка, часы, фотографический 
аппарат — не говорят больше всяких слов об 
интересном госте? (Пришв.); 


Таким образом, однородный ряд в пределах простого предложения может обособляться двумя тире. А когда  второе тире может опускаться?


Это возможно в сложных предложениях, когда однородным рядом заканчивается простое предложение в составе сложного (ставится запятая), а далее следует вторая часть сложной конструкции, например:
Рады сообщить, что теперь через маркетплейсы можно приобрести и непродовольственные товары – одежду, обувь, косметику и прочее, что удобно как продавцам, так и покупателям.
Из пункта 8:
Если по условиям контекста после однородных членов 
предложения требуется постановка запятой, то она ставится, а 
тире или ставится, или опускается.  Владелец тщательно 
осведомляется о ценах на разные большие произведения, как- 
то: муку, пеньку, мёд и прочее, но покупает только небольшие 
безделушки (Г.) — запятая как бы «поглощает» тире.


Скажите, пожалуйста, а можно ли тут обойтись без второго тире? Следить за домом – косить, убирать, вовремя вывозить мусор, должен собственник.

Нет, здесь нужно второе тире, так как однородный ряд находится внутри простого предложения.
